# Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype after maven build

Tags: java, maven

We have an interface `ABC` in our project in module P. We are using maven to build the code. The interface is as below

```
interface ABC{
    public void methodX();
}
```

The `methodX()` is overridden in class `XYZ` with `@Override` annotation of Module Q and implemented. The maven build is working fine since many days.

I have added a new method to this Interface

```
interface ABC{
    public void methodX();
    public void methodY();
}
```

I have overridden this method `methodY()` in Class `XYZ` with `@Override` annotation, and performed build.
The build throws the error

> Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I have added the depedencies of the modules properly. I am using Java 1.8. Please let me know any configuration is missing.

The same error is found in this [link](http://www.filsa.net/2008/02/11/maven-and-the-method-does-not-override-a-method-from-its-superclass-error/).

I have tried that too but the issue persists.

Note: The error is thrown at the line where annoation @Override is present. Is there any other syntax for overriding methods of Interface in Java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you build your module that contains the interface first (mvn install) and afterward you could build the class XYZ

Comment: I am using the command mvn clean install -DskipTests=true on whole project. dont know how to build individual modules

Comment: you could navigate into the module and do the same. how's your project organized?

Comment: layered wisee, presentation, Core, etc. The Interface is in Core module and Class is in presentation. Here is a catch. The method is called from a class PQR which is from module Core-Impl. The dependency of Core is in Presentation and Core in Core-Impl. All the modules are in a single folder DFRE and build is done on it.

Comment: Let me understand this bit: Core has no dependencies to Presentation and Core-Impl?
if yes navigate into core module from the command line and mvn install from there, this would add core into your local repo.

Comment: the dependency of core is added both in Presentation and Core-impl.

Comment: from aforementioned you need to build core, presentation and then core-impl in that order. I assume there is some dependency between presentation and core-impl

Comment: There is no dependency between presentation and core-Impl. As per design, the Core Impl is completely seperated with presentation. It is not added. The only connectivity is Core between them

Comment: I assume that you have (setup|https://github.com/kire9dk/maven-modules)

Comment: Yes. This way setup but not with GIT HUB

Comment: how was your usual way of working before adding the new method?

Comment: The same way no changes whatsoever before adding the method

Comment: Could you do me a favor and write it step by step

Comment: Do you require code? I meant  implementation in this way.

Comment: No, I would like to read the procedure that you are using there to develop. As well as how you project is setup? There are to many gaps.

Comment: Its a very big layered architecutre with different modules. The modules core, core-impl and presentation are in a single layer.

Comment: I think either you IDE has issues to do this or there is some other problem.
If I am debugging this I would execute the modules one by one.
In my example from git hub I would execute core. (mvn clean install) cd into core folder. Then proceed with presentation mvn clean install, and then cd into core-impl mvn clean install. If all this is running then you are good to go. If this fails in the middle then you would have a hint where to look for misconfiguration.

Comment: Before me adding the methodY(), MethodX() is still there and with the same connection between modules, but the application is working fine. I think is it related to the override annotation thats not supported properly for interface methods in java 8, because the error is at override.

Comment: the message "Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" reflects that XYZ is not aware for the new signature of the ABC. This could be since the module that contains XYZ uses an old version of the core.  Maybe purging and re-importing the dependencies would fix it. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Does class XYZ implements ABC? if yes, clean && install from parent project

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: Due to some issues we are building projects on a whole. I have tried this command  which builds the parent project. But unfortunately the same error is thrown

Comment: I have tried to build on the parent project and child ABC project but the buid throws the error.  "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Comment: is Presentation dependency added to Core impl Module?

Comment: No as per design, the Core Impl is completely seperated with presentation. It is not added. The only connectivity is Core between them. An earlier method is working successfully since days. then why a new method is causing this much time.

Comment: Caus your Core Impl Module dont see the new Core(.jar) artefact after you add the new method in it

Comment: do it manually , try to copy Core.jar && Presentation.jar to CoreImpl Classpath , just for test if that work

Comment: workspace -> parent project ->child project -> target or from your maven local repository

Comment: there is only core.jar, IS the build required?

Comment: you need Presentation.jar , if there is no presentation.jar in Core impl you will have an error execution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148023/discussion-between-yugerten-and-nike).

Comment: We will disuss more on chat probaly after a couple of days which I would like know the root cause. Currently I am trying with a new interface for the methodY() and then following with the connectivity of the three modules.

Comment: Added a new interface but still the build throws "Cannot find symbol" on the new interface. I have run mvn clean install. Now I am trying with mvn clean package